# Remove the Sunday on DateTime And Execute On For Loop In Datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I'm creating a for loop to execute the date on C# Window Form datagrid. But My problem is, I want to disregard the "Sunday."

Here's my code

```
var fromDate = date_from.Value; // tool from datetime

// My For Loop
int count;
for (count = 0; count < 45; count++)
{
    if (fromDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        // Remove the sunday code        
    }
    else 
    {
       fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1); //
    }

    dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = fromDate.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to skip the sunday part you can try the below code if you afford to show empty string enstead of the date.

```
var fromDate = date_from.Value; // tool from datetime
// My For Loop
for (int count = 0; count < 45; count++)
{
    if (fromDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
       fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    if(fromDate > date_from.Value.AddDays(45))
       break;
    dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = fromDate.ToShortDateString();
    fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1);

}
```

Comment: When I use the continue, it only execute 9,10 only. 11 and others didn't appear because its sunday.

Comment: @mark its beacause you were not incrementing the date if its sunday. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Sir, Is there a way that I can delete the whole date? Its just hiding the day sir.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your requirement. I think you dont want to display date if day is Sunday. In you code you are first checking for sunday and then adding a day to fromDate. But, if day is saturday.. then sunday will be displayed.

```
     for (count = 0; count < 45; count++)
{
    fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1); 

    if (fromDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        // Remove the sunday code        
        fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1); 
    }

    dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = fromDate.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: I mean sir, What I want to display the date within 45 days except the sunday

Comment: None of my days added to one. Still, when I choose the day 9, all of the date is 9.

Comment: Better you post your actual output and expected output.